# How to use regex for extract domain parts from string

Tags: ruby

I have a URL string like `"https://example.com"`. I want to show the parts of this URL like protocol, domain, and extension. How can I do this using regular expression?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: No, I have no any Idea about that

Comment: Try http://rubular.com/. It teaches and gives you the playground to learn regular expressions.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html and http://rubular.com should help you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ruby I have used something like this

```
user:~/workspace $ irb
2.3.4 :018 > url = "https://example.com"
 => "https://.example.com" 
2.3.4 :019 > u = url.match(/(?<protocol>[\w]+):\/\/(?<domain>[\w-]+)\.(?<extension>\w+)/)
 => #<MatchData "https://example.com" protocol:"https" domain:"example" extension:"com"> 
2.3.4 :020 > u[:protocol]
 => "https" 
2.3.4 :021 > u[:domain]
 => "example" 
2.3.4 :022 > u[:extension]
 => "com"
```

If you have also subdomain then use like below regular expression

```
2.3.4 :034 > url = "https://sub.example.com"    
2.3.4 :035 > u = url.match(/(?<protocol>[\w]+):\/\/(?<domain>[[a-zA-Z0-9]\.-]+)\.(?<extension>\w+)/)
 => #<MatchData "https://sub.example.com" protocol:"https" domain:"sub.example" extension:"com"> 
2.3.4 :036 > u[:protocol]
 => "https" 
2.3.4 :037 > u[:domain]
 => "sub.example" 
2.3.4 :038 > u[:extension]
 => "com"
```

In the `http://rubular.com/` I have created a snippet for testing regular expression which not failing with `subdomain` see this [***`Rubular`***](http://rubular.com/r/qfTLJgn9m4)

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use a ruby built-in class for this:

```
uri = URI("http://www.example.com")
uri.scheme // http
uri.host // www.example.com
```

See also: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: Question says to use Regex to extract the parts of URL.

Comment: I think OP just wants to solve the problem. I'm pointing out there are alternatives to using regex'es. As you know these are quite complex for URI's. Especially if you want to fetch path, params & anchors later on.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh this particular question must be answered with **one doesn’t use regex to parse domain names**.

Comment: Agree, maybe only for form validation.